# When using Moment.js, the values of startOf and endOf seem strange

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm going to use `Moment.js` to find the beginning and end of the query time.

I wrote the code as follows, and here's the result.

**Code**

```
const m = moment(); // "2023-01-18T15:59:12.064Z"
const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone; // "UTC"
const beginDate = moment().startOf('day').toDate();
const endDate   = moment().endOf('day').toDate();

console.log(beginDate);
console.log(endDate);
```

**Result**

```
"2023-01-18T00:00:00.000Z"
"2023-01-18T23:59:59.999Z"
```

Is there any influence of local time zone in this code? The above code is the result of calling a function on the Node.js server in the `KST (UTC+9)` time zone.

The actual Date value is `15:59:12`, so can't I set `15:00:00` as the start time?

Comment: It seems you’re asking quite a few distinct questions here, can you limit to a single inquiry in accordance with [ask]?

Comment: "Why are the start and end times viewed on a 24-hour basis?" because that's what you asked for? Why would you expect `.startOf('day')` to be 3pm? "So can't I set 15:00:00 as the start time?" yes, you can do that, but you have to write code that does that... did you mean `.startOf('hour')`?

Comment: I thought about it again after seeing the answer. I think the `startOf()` result was `3pm` due to the influence of `UTC+9`. However, if you look at the logs on the server, I think `24:00:00` is correct because it is `UTC+0`.